# What is StackExchange's policy regarding "where should I ask this question?" type questions?

Tags: discussion, scope

I have asked questions on Stackoverflow that were simply moved to a different StackExchange site because someone deemed the different site more appropriate.

Yesterday I asked this question on ServerFault;

"Is there a serverfault/stackoverflow - style site for SEO questions?"

Instead of being moved or even having the question answered, it was downvoted six time and closed!

What should I do if I don't know where to ask a question? What is the policy of the StackExchange group regarding a question like the above? Was it appropriate for it to be closed instead of moved?

I am now scared to ask questions on ServerFault because I fear being downvoted.

Comment: For your original question: webmasters.stackexchange.com looks like the right site.

Comment: see http://stackexchange.com/sites -- that's the directory.

Answer (score 12):

In the case of posting "where should I ask X?" on a site (ServerFault or any other one), there is no pre-defined migration path to Meta Stack Overflow (this site) which would be the best option. I guess people didn't feel that migrating to ServerFault's meta was appropriate either, since the question isn't about ServerFault. It was clearly off-topic and so it was closed.

You've come to the right place now, though. "Where should I ask X?" questions would fit great here on Meta.

You can also look through [the site list on stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/sites) and see if you can find an appropriate site that way. If you think you found the site you want, you can also post on that site's meta to double-check that your question would fit well there.

Comment: Do you think it makes for a rather intimidating atmosphere if simply asking "where should I ask..." gets downvoted and closed?

Comment: @Nigel I can see how it could. I'm really surprised nobody pointed you in the right direction in a comment, and 6 downvotes was probably excessive. But I definitely don't think the question should've been left open or formally answered. An off-topic question is an off-topic question.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't ask questions *about* Server Fault on Server Fault. Those are very likely to be downvoted and closed. People have little sympathy for this, as the FAQ explains that meta questions belong on the separate Meta sites. It's perfectly OK to ask questions about server and network administration, though, because those *are* on-topic. You shouldn't fear downvotes for those questions.

Questions *about* the sites should be directed to the per-site metas (such as [Meta Server Fault](http://meta.serverfault.com/)) or the main meta (this one). Use the [site-rec](/questions/tagged/site-rec) tag on your question to indicate that you're looking for a recommendation of the best place to ask your question.

Also, as Anna mentions, you can try to find the best site on your own by browsing the complete list of sites on the [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/sites) website. And don't worry too much if you try to pick the right site, but enough community members disagree with you to migrate the question elsewhere. This is what migration is designed for, and it shouldn't be interpreted as an insult or a punishment when it happens.

Comment: I don't feel that migration is an insult at all - it's very helpful! What is insulting is asking a question like "Where should I ask..." and getting downvoted. It feels like the "question police" are out there waiting to pounce on anyone who gets it slightly wrong. It's like the bad guys have found "legal" way to vent their smug unhelpful nastiness. It felt like being bullied. I have never been jumped on in that way at stackoverflow.

Comment: @Nigel: I am absolutely stunned that you've read all of that from a couple of downvotes cast on your question. Maybe people just *didn't like the question*. There's no way to tell whether those downvotes were because they thought it was "off-topic".

Comment: Yes there is. I asked! Someone replied "Massively off-topic questions get downvoted". And it wasn't "a couple" of downvotes. At one point it was eight